# How can I get Microsoft Command Line Utilities 14 for SQL Server to install?

Tags: windows, sql-server

In order to run a third-party WSUS script (against the Windows Internal Database) I downloaded the x64 version of the [Microsoft Command Line Utilities 14 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591), but when I attempt the installation I get the following error message:

> Setup is missing an installation prerequisite: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.  To continue, install Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server and then run the Setup operation again.

Installing the ODBC driver (downloaded from [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)) as instructed has no effect, I still get the same error message when attempting to install the command line utilities.

Also, although I definitely downloaded the "Microsoft Command Line Utilities *14* for SQL Server" when I run the installer it is titled "Microsoft Command Line Utilities *13* for SQL Server".

(Emphasis mine.)

What the heck is going on here and how can I successfully install the latest version of the command line utilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is correctly indicating that a prerequisite is missing, but does not correctly show which prerequisite is actually needed.

What you actually need is the [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339).

---

As for the version number discrepancy, according to Programs and Features, the "version 14" download is for version 14.0 of the Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server.  The digital signature is dated December 2017.

By way of comparison, the download labelled [Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52680) appears in Programs and Features as version 11.3 of the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities.  The digital signature is dated October 2015.

So while the versioning may be hopelessly confused, these are at least definitely two different downloads, and the "version 14" download is newer.

Comment: This saved me some time!